# Sensor out of bounds

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I've attached the result of the rxgraph. I've created a node which is sending commands to the move_base_node, my map is a static one published by map_server, I'm using amcl to obtain the map->odom transform. My configure files are ok, in the global_costmap my map is set to static. I'm getting the following error.

```
The origin for the sensor at (0.15, -0.00) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
```

> 

Im sending the following goal coordinates (wx,wy)

```
wx=-0.014118, wy=-0.031483, mx=4, my=3
```

> I'm getting this error, my map is 492x583 with the resolution of 0.016. The map is attached, the robot is set to (0.9, 7.7)

```
The goal sent to the navfn planner is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail to this goal.
```

Thank you!
[Gazebo_robot.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13063337735392647.png),[amcl_outofbounds.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13063337869111723.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10029/sensor-out-of-bounds/) by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not use a static map from one source and the transformation from another. They don't match this way.
If you want to use a static map from the map server, use localization.
This tutorial shows how to use it: [Using custom maps](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/UsingCustomMapForSimulation)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4